# Filter ng-model before inserting to text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

**Is there a `Angular` way to filter data being displayed inside a `textbox`?**

I have date data to be displayed in `textbox`,currently i make a new variable and format it using `moment js`,and i have to write `$scope.$watch()` over the first variable to reflect changes over the other.In this example it seems OK, but when i apply it to my project it's slowing it down,so i want to know, is there any angular methodology for the same

```js
var app = angular.module('xample', []);
app.controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.date = moment();
  vm.d2 = vm.date.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="xample">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <p>Real Date</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.date">
    <p>Filtered in controller</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.d2">
  </div>

  <body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since model `date` and model `d2` are separated inside your controller you need to use Angular's [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) listener.
Keep in mind that you may also use the [date filter component](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) instead of parsing date objects with moment.js

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.date = moment();
  $scope.d2 = $scope.date.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
  $scope.$watch('date', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.d2 = moment(newValue).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
  });
}]);

app.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
}]);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/21122/)

Comment: So you are saying that there is no built in functionality that can filter data before inserting to a textbox ?

Comment: You may use the predefined $filter options, custom filter formatting methods or even your own functions. Binding data to your view needs model assignments to UI elements like textboxes. You should read and understand how angular works first. One way or another you may use `ng-value` to map filtered data from a model. Take a look at the following example http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/21124/

Comment: Sorry,but i just need a method in which i can preserve the data and display the formatted data without using `$watch`